# How to induce artificial gangrene?

Tags: anatomy, diseases, medicine

A crazy dictator is once again bored of the most gruesome execution methods invented by the leading torturers and doctors of the country. He tasks the employees of his favorite torture center with inventing various methods to effectively artificially induce diseases such as cancer on healthy individuals to allow for a slow and painful death.

You are one of the executioners employed in this institution. Waiting for a promotion, you accept this task and choose Gangrene as the disease. You have to:

- develop an effective method to quickly artificially induce

  - dry gangrene
  - wet gangrene
  - gas gangrene
  - other forms of progressive necrosis

  in any given appendage or tissue of a human, with the ability to control the progression of the disease with the intent to make it as painful as possible and prolong the suffering of the subject.

I imagine methods like injecting aggressive bacteria or flaying skin and applying dirt on the exposed muscle tissue.

Comment: Gangrene is caused by insufficient blood supply. Therefore apply a tourniquet to your favorite (or least favorite) limb of the torturee, and wait for necrosis to set in. Also, send in some Komodo Dragons to play with him/her if you want to speed up the process.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question hits the very limits of good taste. I couldn't find a proper category to flag it into, though, so here is a brief answer about what gangrene is and how it comes into being. And the only way I could think of to make it controlled all the way to death.

---

All quotes are from Wikipedia.

> Gangrene (or gangrenous necrosis) is a type of necrosis caused by a critically insufficient blood supply.

### Dry gangrene

> Dry gangrene is a form of coagulative necrosis that develops in ischemic tissue, where the blood supply is inadequate to keep tissue viable. Dry gangrene is often due to peripheral artery disease, but can be due to acute limb ischemia.
>
> Acute limb ischaemia (ALI) occurs when there is a sudden lack of blood flow to a limb.

Make turniquet on limb to cut off blood flow. Control progression by applying tourniquet a bit higher once the tissue below is dead. A human has four limbs that can be treated that way. If that still isn't enough sadism, men have genitals and women have breasts.

### Wet Gangrene, gaseous gangrene

Wikipedia:

> Wet, or infected, gangrene is characterized by thriving bacteria and has a poor prognosis
>
> Gas gangrene is a bacterial infection that produces gas within tissues.

Not recommended if you want to keep your prisoner alive for a long time

> due to sepsis resulting from the free communication between infected fluid and circulatory fluid.
>
> Sepsis is a life-threatening condition that arises when the body's response to infection injures its own tissues and organs.

Trying to keep a patient with sepsis alive is quite hard, and it always necessitates treating the origin of the sepsis -- the wet / gaseous gangrene you just tried to induce. Too much effort and too much chance involved to make a good torture method out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Have Torturer Bob start looking at our friend the Brown Recluse Spider (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_recluse_spider).  Brown Recluse spider bites can occasionally cause a sort of progressive tissue necrosis which is similar to small scale Gangrene.

So Torturer Bob starts talking to to Sally in the mad science department and they come up with a way to synthesize the recluse venom.

Here is how it becomes a rather nasty torture:  The bite of a brown Recluse often goes totally unnoticed.  It then starts to itch, followed by pain.  As the tissue dies off, nerves become exposed before they die, much like a 2nd and 3rd degree burn.  Ouch.  You have all sorts of options when the victim has some open sores.  You have the added benefit of being able to keep control of the level of infection and so on, unlike with massive sepsis that can happen with Wet or Gas Gangrene.

Answer (score 1):

**HAVE YOUR FASCIST REGIME FOLLOW THE EXAMPLE OF ANOTHER FASCIST REGIME**

**NAMELY, THE NATZIS**

The natzi's did things to prisoners at Ravensbruck that are very similar to what your dictator wants to do. To quote [this article](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/holocaust/experiside.html),

> They inflicted battlefield-like wounds in victims, then infected the wounds with bacteria such as streptococcus, tetanus, and gas gangrene. The doctors aggravated the resulting infection by rubbing ground glass and wood shavings into the wound, and they tied off blood vessels on either side of the injury to simulate what would happen to an actual war wound.

Of course, the goal there was to find ways to "treat wounds in the field", namely wounds caused by Gas Gangrene, a serious problem for soldiers on the eastern front. But to find out how to treat it, they first had to give it the prisoners. Your dictator could use similar methods to the natzi doctors, the only exception being that he never bothers to "treat" the "war wounds".

Comment: I remember reading about this a while back. Gruesome, what dark pages of medicine exist if you bother looking...